# The backup set holds a backup of a database other than the existing-Differential backup

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, database-administration, database-backups, database-restore

I have a backup copy of the site i inherited from a different developer. When i try to restore it, i get the below error:

> The backup set holds a backup of a database other than the existing 'databasename' database.

I have done almost everything listed but i can't get it work. When I do RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM DISK. I get three entries:

[image]

Please let me know if i am missing something here. I don't have the full backup anywhere.

Comment: [some searches lead me to this](https://www.google.com.au/search?source=hp&q=The+backup+set+holds+a+backup+of+a+database+other+than+the+existing+%27databasename%27+database&oq=The+backup+set+holds+a+backup+of+a+database+other+than+the+existing+%27databasename%27+database&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i13k1.1583.1583.0.2489.1.1.0.0.0.0.139.139.0j1.1.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.1.138....0.xdul58wr26w)

Comment: How will you restore the differential backup without having full backup?

Comment: The only backup that i have is this differential backup file. This differential backup file has "bak_part-524288000-629145599" to it. I am not a big SQL person but i have restored many back ups and i havent seen anything like this before.